# Custom Role Provider not working - Instant redirect to login page after logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, roleprovider

I have made a custom Role Provider. Before I updated my VS and NuGet packages everything seemed to work. However, when I login now it looks like the pages gets refreshed (or the View is reloaded atleast). I do see a cookie is created though, but I will not get redirect to Index. Why?

In my Web.Config:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="project.Authorisation.CustomRoleProvider" />
        <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

In my HomeController:

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool authenticated = userDBController.isAuthorized(user.Nickname, user.Password);

            if (authenticated)
            {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Nickname, false);
                    return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Inlog data is incorrect!";
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

So when I logged in I cannot go to Home/Index, it will redirect me to Login anyways. Same for after logging in.

My Custom RoleProvider is quite simple right now:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private MainController mainController = MainController.Instance;
    private UserDBController userDBController = MainController.Instance.GetUserDBController();

public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    return userDBController.getRollen(username);
}
```

Before everything, this all worked (also the authorization).

Comment: Make sure that the connected user has Admin role.

Comment: The user I am logging in with does have the admin role. However, If I put a breakpoint at GetRoleForUser function, it does not get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found out what was the issue!

Appearently after reinstalling packages and what not my web.config was changed. All I had to do is add enabled="true" to the roleManager section. Therefore the code should look like:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="project.Authorisation.CustomRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

So appearently the rolemanager is disabled.
I hope this will help other people who might experience this problem!